# Force HTTPS on my rewrite and rule .htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

I would like to force https on my site but that it is compatible with the current rule of my .htaccess

Here is my htaccess file at the moment :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, where you need to look for condition if variable `%{HTTPS}` is on or not, add this condition with already existing condition. Also please don't mix it with already existing URL as it may get expose to client/browser(taking example from your shown current example).

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your help ! 
When i add your proposition i get a ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: @IlannJoaquim, as anubhava sir asked in comments, could you please do let us know if you already have few rules in your htaccess? Try putting this rule in starting of it.

Comment: Yes I put it at the beginning, and my .htaccess look exactly the same as the proposition of RavinderSingh13, but i get the error too many redirect

Comment: @IlannJoaquim, when I tested this, it worked for me fine. Could you please restart apache once and check again? Though I am not sure about why its not working.

Comment: I don't have access to apache on my web host service :/

Comment: @liann: Instead of `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off` try: `RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on`. Also tell your Apache version?

Comment: @IlannJoaquim It depends on how the SSL is handled on your system. If the SSL cert is installed directly on the application server then the above should work in the majority of cases. However, if you are using a front end SSL proxy to manage the HTTPS then the above will likely result in a redirect loop because the connection between the application server and the proxy is likely to be HTTP, not HTTPS. So, you need to know how the SSL is managed... SSL proxy? Cloudflare Flexible SSL? It can also be quite non-standard on some shared hosts, requiring the use of specific env vars instead.