# how to redirect https://www.example.com/aaa to https://example.com/aaa/

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I use this one to force the trailing slash. But it is not working for example.com
example.com or [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) should be redirected to https://example.com/

````
```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} GET
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /+[^\.]+$ 
RewriteRule ^(.+[^/])$ %{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```
````

Help me please.

Comment: That `/` after `example.com` is stripped by browsers and you cannot force that using redirect rules.

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following, try to put this in starting of your htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,QSA,NC]
```

NOTE: This will also depend on how SSL is handled on your system, see this very informative and descriptive comment from @MrWhite [Force HTTPS on my rewrite and rule .htaccess file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64594041/force-https-on-my-rewrite-and-rule-htaccess-file/64594359?noredirect=1#comment114219745_64594359)